# Laravel 5.7 + Intervention Image : Image source not readable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, intervention

I've create an app that upload image along with title, description & etc. However, i'm having a problem in some of the images to upload, it returns an error ("Image source not readable") as shown below:

[image]

Here's my Code:

```
$image = $request->file('image');
// $image = Input::file('image'); // already tried this one still same problem

$orginal_filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileName = md5(microtime() . $orginal_filename) . '.' . $ext;

$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$img->stream();
$img->resize(1200, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
}); 

Storage::disk('storage_dir')->put($dir . $fileName, $img, 'public');
```

Already tried following solutions:

- Change to Input::file('file')
- Check if Request Content-Type has multipart/form-data **(Request already has multipart/form-data Content-Type)**
- Change Intervention Image driver from "gd" to "imagick"

but still have the "Image source not readable" error.

**Note**: Error only occurs in some images. (I've also tried moving the image(w/c produced the errors) into another directory but still error occurs).

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: are you using HTML form to upload image  ?

Comment: Try first to see what the type of the Images, to can use this command to see what is the format: identify "IMG PATH"

Comment: I'm using an HTML form, append it into a FormData then sent a post request
@Muhammad Sipra

Comment: @Ali Mohammed, sorry i don't get it, can u please elaborate?

Comment: @EdwinBermejo, please check your input parameters specifically your image parameter by printing your parameters on the server side. In this way, we would be able to see that what kind of data you are receiving from your form

Comment: @EdwinBermejo, for example, we need to check if the image is supported by imagick, because some formate of images is not supported like HEIC/HEIF format, you can check what is the format of the image from the command line:  identify "IMG PATH"

Comment: @Ali Mohammed already tried checking the image format, it is a JPEG. Already looked in intervention image docs also and now know that JPEG is both supported by GD and imagick driver but still have same issue.

Comment: Here' an update, i tried showing the image realpath ($img->getRealPath()) and find out that the image that i'm having the problem is not saving to xampp's tmp directory but the rest of the images that worked is saved first into the tmp directory then saved into the desired directory.

Maybe someone knows the reason why, Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can try running my code

```
if ($request->file('photo')->isValid()) {
        $avatar = $request->file('photo');

        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) );

    }
```

**/uploads/avatars/** is my directory

Comment: Thanks for this one, need this also ^_^

Answer (score 5):

If the problem occours in a Laravel 5.7 project, and you store your pictures in the storage folder, it might solve the problem to enter this into the terminal:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

(The problem occurs if you have cloned the project from github og bitbucket)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for bothering guys! It seemed that it was all my fault not realizing `php post_max_size` and `php upload_max_file_size`. Since i was trying to upload an image larger than 8MB i only increased the `post_max_size` > than the current image file size, but not the `upload_max_file_size` coz i only increased it by 2 (stated: 4MB).

Thanks btw for the help and suggestions!

Comment: For some reason, this solved my problem. The `upload_max_file_size` of my server is only 2MB, while I'm uploading a 4MB document. 

What a deceiving error message that is!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$resize = Image::make('storage/app/public/'.$user->image)->resize(300,300);
```

with

```
$resize = Image::make(storage_path('app/public/'.$user->image))->resize(300,300);
```

Give storage full path will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error on your server, you need to be sure you pushed the all images to server. You are facing this error because of server could not find or read to image/images.

**-> Be sure image/images uploaded 

-> Make readable to image/images.**